# Is there a javascript framework to apply rules for dynamic changes of form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a javascript framework to apply rules for dynamic changes of form.
My web application is written in ASP.NET MVC 5. I have a one big form where states of some controls are driven by values of other (e.g. when user change value in select to "b", this change should implicate other changes - some controls should be hidden, some labels should change text, some textbox should change their own value, which implicates some other changes etc. When I get back to "a", changes should be withdrawn).

I want to:

- avoid some spaghetti, ugly javascript code with many ifs, elses and change events
- hold business rules in business layer (e.g. in XML file) and push them to client-side inside ViewModel. I can write my own parser to apply rules
- solution must be generic (one solution for all forms, the only difference between them is a static file with rules)
- solution should be client-side (without AJAX and page reloading)

Do you know something that can fulfill my needs?

EDIT:

I have this XML file with rules. There is a logical OR between Groups and a logical AND between Conditions. In other words - if in any group all conditions are fulfilled - action should be executed (e.g. show element), otherwise, reverse action (e.g. hide element).

I don't want to re-write this logic on client-side (e.g. as a part of knockout ViewModel), rather I want to apply it to something similar to business rule engine, which can handle all logic execution for me.
Do you know any framework that can work this way?

```
<ValidationModel>
    <Action Obj="manual-edit-block" Type="Visible">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="E" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="details-block" Type="Visible">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="C" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="details-representative-block" Type="Visible">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="E" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="allows-unassign-block" Type="Visible">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="E" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="algorithm-block" Type="Visible">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="G" />
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="D" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="algorithm_base" Type="Value" Value="12">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="G" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="algorithm_base" Type="Value" Value="15">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="1" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="G" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
    <Action Obj="identifier-block" Type="Visible">
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="E" />
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="source-type" Type="EQUAL" Val="F" />
            <Condition Neg="0" Obj="algorithm_base" Type="HASCLASS" Val="valid" />
        </Group>
    </Action>
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: have you checked out knockoutjs, angularjs etc?? Besides I agree with @Lix. You question is too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: I've edited my post to point what exactly is my problem. I'm currently working on my own implementation, but I want to know if there is an existing alternative which I can use. I don't know and I can't find any.

Comment: I think KnockoutJS is the way to go here. It easily implements into existing projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [nools](http://c2fo.github.io/nools) is what I am looking for. It provides nice rule syntax and works  client-side.